# Flutter Web Sockets Not Connecting to Laravel

Tags: android, laravel, flutter, sockets, websocket

Using this package https://pub.dev/packages/laravel_echo

**Current Code**

```
import 'package:example/modal.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:laravel_echo/laravel_echo.dart';
import 'package:flutter_pusher_client/flutter_pusher.dart';

class PusherPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _PusherPage();
}

class _PusherPage extends State<PusherPage> {
  List<String> _logs = new List();
  Echo echo;
  bool isConnected = false;
  String channelType = 'public';
  String channelName = '';
  String event;
  FlutterPusher pusherClient;

  void onConnectionStateChange(ConnectionStateChange event) {
    if (event.currentState == 'CONNECTED') {
      log('connected');
      setState(() {
        isConnected = true;
      });
    } else if (event.currentState == 'DISCONNECTED') {
      log('disconnected');
      setState(() {
        isConnected = false;
      });
    }
  }

  FlutterPusher getPusherClient() {
    PusherOptions options = PusherOptions(
      host: 'http://192.168.0.164:8000/laravel-websockets',
      port: 6001,
      encrypted: false,
    );
    return FlutterPusher('Laravel', options, lazyConnect: true);
  }

  void connect() {
    pusherClient.connect(onConnectionStateChange: this.onConnectionStateChange);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    pusherClient = getPusherClient();

    echo = new Echo({
      'broadcaster': 'pusher',
      'client': pusherClient,
      // 'auth': {
      //   'headers': {
      //     'Authorization':
      //         'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImp0aSI6IjFkNTcxYzcyMTcwZmFmNDRmM2JkYjdkZTE2NmVmNTMzZTMwYjYwNjI2MjA5NjJlNWFhMmNkNTkyOTgwMzNlZmVlMjMyNzI2YTczMTY2NGZiIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIxIiwianRpIjoiMWQ1NzFjNzIxNzBmYWY0NGYzYmRiN2RlMTY2ZWY1MzNlMzBiNjA2MjYyMDk2MmU1YWEyY2Q1OTI5ODAzM2VmZWUyMzI3MjZhNzMxNjY0ZmIiLCJpYXQiOjE1NTAyNTE4MzIsIm5iZiI6MTU1MDI1MTgzMiwiZXhwIjoxNTgxNzg3ODMyLCJzdWIiOiIxIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbXX0.Yhmzofhp8q32gcFmzQDAmm48cwmxqrZAi4Mfsbzp6pyzjzWziEM8isDrNqyQZANXUJP40LGJroK9LkVddHyqWtPQqTNXPv-Azx3tVy_YOkI-BhJhttKaiN7DTPD9gYiuUpINUjrqTVuzxzDHzXNmTemOVqVBABo4f6m9ZoWkdyNKyirPZHagofs4Lp1YR0--AgItZVCPl3DYrLdMY78a687edQaYA1q3HKWPggtxayN35BPoeOm08uxmE_YzYXRTzi6OxGLNcQnrC61NvWqTCZ5Ze4fvUuVRtASqybV1Y4oxcgs2kZYg1rxm5idHUrGwQE4fLmaGgDclBR7Ax-NbiN-VN1gJpB2D7eVYxigCVsCVBnoA5DtjKewg0axckthTXyxcTWJBnbarbbnPuI9ZWrxaZWcp4kWwosw9_pr7Ee_5Q-Uxr_ksZg6qZ3gVrqR9ZY0zZoQl4qEsbUGfLXLGrKj_NjeESOcUsPY6fACIy_Okttxto_a3y9wQwPMDJY-jxdLdZ1TdusZUJG8d5KJxfOUprqsCzju-TVnLZxpA-f15mI9zIcjtA-2PFYnUuukIxBw-FXzBWssrMLyTXxHl9Sux3WH5mtXDW_wbwoJj6aaLHBw28jgokbdlKx3QRWdTvAsALJM6nmDN4BWu2pIn05i5wpcUnxHIvcdOgoh3hn0'
      //   }
      // }
    });
  }

  log(String event) {
    var now = new DateTime.now();
    String formatted =
        "${now.hour.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${now.minute.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${now.second.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}";

    setState(() {
      _logs.insert(0, "$formatted $event");
    });
  }

  void _listenToChannel(String type, String name, String event) {
    dynamic channel;

    if (type == 'public') {
      channel = echo.channel(name);
    } else if (type == 'private') {
      channel = echo.private(name);
    } else if (type == 'presence') {
      channel = echo.join(name).here((users) {
        print(users);
      }).joining((user) {
        print(user);
      }).leaving((user) {
        print(user);
      });
    }

    channel.listen(event, (e) {
      log('channel: $name, event: $event');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoPageScaffold(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
              color: Colors.grey[100],
              child: ListView.builder(
                reverse: true,
                itemCount: _logs.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4),
                    child: Text(_logs[index]),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 70,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border(
                top: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[300]),
              ),
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: <Widget>[
                  CupertinoButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      showCupertinoModalPopup<void>(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return ChannelModal(
                            listen: true,
                            type: channelType,
                            name: channelName,
                            onTypeChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                channelType = value;
                              });
                            },
                            onNameChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                channelName = value;
                              });
                            },
                            onEventChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                event = value;
                              });
                            },
                            onSubmit: () {
                              log('Listening to channel: $channelName');
                              _listenToChannel(channelType, channelName, event);
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                    child: Text('listen to channel'),
                  ),
                  CupertinoButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      showCupertinoModalPopup<void>(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return ChannelModal(
                            listen: false,
                            name: channelName,
                            onNameChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                channelName = value;
                              });
                            },
                            onSubmit: () {
                              log('Leaving channel: $channelName');
                              echo.leave(channelName);
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                    child: Text('leave channel'),
                  ),
                  Visibility(
                    visible: !isConnected,
                    child: CupertinoButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        log('connecting');
                        this.connect();
                      },
                      child: Text('connect'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Visibility(
                    visible: isConnected,
                    child: CupertinoButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        log('disconnecting');
                        echo.disconnect();
                      },
                      child: Text('disconnect'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  CupertinoButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      dynamic id = echo.sockedId();
                      log('socket_id: $id');
                    },
                    child: Text('get socket-id'),
                  ),
                  CupertinoButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        _logs = [];
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text('clear log'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

All i've changed is the host and port number.
The link http://192.168.0.164:8000/laravel-websockets is valid and takes me to the Laravel WebSockets Dashboard both on the Phone Browser and PC Browser so the IP and everything is correct. I'm just unable to connect it using the app

**Error**

```
W/System.err( 6777): SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
W/System.err( 6777): SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
W/System.err( 6777): SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Any Help would be Appreciated.